# how do you set the value in a dropdown programatically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

if i have a dropdown with the following html:

```
 <select id="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
<option value="6">Six</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

how can i have this dropdown change to a specific selected value after i click on a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your button is `id="myButton"` you can do it like this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").val(1); //1 being whatever value you want to set
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(".mybuttonclass").click(function() {
           $(".myDropdownclass").val(value for that dropdown items);  
  });
  });
```